# How can I select groups of strings from an array where not all groups contain the same contents?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an array list with the following string content. Each line represents a different object in the array. The strings in the array list are consecutive, without any spacing between the objects.

```
Term: Intelligent Power-Modul
TermType: MainTerm
Term: Intelligent Power Modul
TermType: NegativeTerm
Term: IPM
TermType: Abbreviation

Term: wired remote
TermType: MainTerm
Definition: a wired remote
```

I want to select objects based on the TermType value.

I can't make a constructor with Term, TermType, and Definition, because Definition doesn't always appear (there are groups of objects without an associated Definition). How do I map the various terms in a group that are differentiated by the TermType?

Comment: Make each term type a class.

Comment: I second @shmosel's suggestion to create a class. I think it should be a `Term` class that represents each term. Then you can parse the file and create instances of that class.

Comment: But they don't belong together.

The upper group has nothing to do with the other. If I were to make a class for every TermType, I would put them together, wouldn't I?

Comment: Only type-wise.

Comment: *But they don't belong together* - then why are they in the same list?